# Microsoft Universal app bundle error when compiling

Tags: sqlite, azure, universal

I'm building a Universal app that includes SqLiteStore.  I'm getting this odd error includes misspellings.  SQLite doesn't let me pick AnyCPU so I'm at a conundrum.  Any ideas on where to look?

error APPX3104: You cannot create an app bundle when building for platform 'x86' which is not included in the list of platforms selected for producting app bundle. Set platform to a one of following values: AnyCPU.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the supported platforms list is set by the `AppxBundlePlatforms` property. Try something like this:

*msbuild Foo.sln /p:Platform=x86;PlatformTarget=x86;Configuration=Release;AppxBundle=Always;**AppxBundlePlatforms=x86***

For more information see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29353229/67824